# Eclipse missing run configurations for tomcat after mvn eclipse:clean

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Today I am facing a somewhat very curious problem within eclipse. I created a `Dynamic Web Project`, added a JSP and a matching servlet class. In my servlet I use another project which I load via maven.

To load the dependency, I navigate to the project folder in my workspace within the `cmd` and execute

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

then I refresh the the project in eclipse via F5. Then I can start my JSP and it is working fine except that I get a `ClassNotFoundException`, but that has nothing to do with my question.

If I by mistake not just execute `mvn eclipse:eclipse` but instead run `mvn eclipse:clean` first, then it removes all my run-configurations for that project.

[image]

Also if I open the Run Configuration window I get 2 errors in a row:

First:
[image]
And second:

[image]
I couldn't find any solution to this except creating a new project and copying the files.

How can I either stop the deletion of the run configurations OR get them back?

Comment: Just an advise : the Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin is retired for a long time. I would not use it with recent Maven and recent Eclipse versions.

Comment: @davidxxx I don't use the plugin. As stated I used command line

Comment: Not sure to understand. `mvn eclipse:clean` refers to this retired plugin. And this plugin is designed to work in command line (it changes the classpath of Eclipse essentially)

Comment: Ohh okay, my bad. I had no problems at all until today and it sometimes is the only way for me to update the dependencies

Comment: Make your launch configurations sharable.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I can't access them because there are none as well as I am having the errors in the alst two pictures

Comment: Start over.  `eclipse:eclipse` rewrites the internal files Eclipse use and your work is lost.  Use m2e instead for this reason.  Make your future launch configurations sharable.

Comment: I am still not able to access any launch configurations for Apache Tomcat. I am thinking about reinstalling eclipse and then only use the m2e